# Serve PHP page in web root but show contents in subdirectories

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, rewrite, rewritecond

I have a web site on a shared hosting server.  My directory layout looks like this

```
/home
    /user
        /public_html
            /pics
                /family
```

There is an index.php file in public_html.  I need help writing .htaccess rules that will

1. Serve the index.php file when www.domain.org is requested
2. Force the user back to public_html when www.domain.org/pics is requested
3. Allow the user to see the directory contents when www.domain.org/pics/family is requested

I experimented with a lot of combinations of RewriteCond and RewriteRule, but I don't understand the documentation and examples well enough to know if what I want to do is even possible.

The web server application is some version of Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this in public_html/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/pics/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/pics/family/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
```

There is nothing in public_html/pics/.htaccess
I put this in public_html/pics/family/.htaccess

```
Options +Indexes
```

I removed index.html.

After that, everything worked the way I wanted it to work.
I got the idea from [this Drupal documentation](http://drupal.org/node/30334).

Answer (score 1):

1) You can get this one for free by adding a `DirectoryIndex index.php` in your .htaccess file that's sitting in public_html.

2) To reroute requests to /pics, you can use this set of rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^pics/?$ http://www.domain.org/ [R,L]
```

3) You'll need to use the  with Options:

```
<Directory "/home/user/public_html/pics/family">
    Options Indexes
</Directory>
```

You'll need to make sure in your webserver conf or virtualhost conf that you can override options in your .htaccess files. Something like `AllowOverride All` or `AllowOverride Indexes`. Also note that with #2, people will still be able to access the files in pics, e.g. http://www.domain.org/pics/pic1.jpg, but will get redirected if attempting to just access the directory.

Comment: I put `DirectoryIndex index.php` in public_html, but it still serves index.html

Comment: Then replace with this rule: `RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]`

Comment: So far, the only success I have is to put `Options Indexes` in pics and family.  My ignorance of the correct syntax for RewriteRule and RewriteCond just causes the server to report 503 or some other error.

Comment: ok.  I have a .htaccess in public_html with only `RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]` and it still serves index.html.  Are there any other lines I need to add, like `RewriteEngine On` or `RewriteBase /`?

Comment: You need `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: Still no joy.  Does it matter that index.php contains `header('Location:http://www.domain.org/site')` which is the directory for a Drupal site?

Comment: If it's still serving the ~/public_html/index.html page, then something else is interferring. It doesn't matter what is inside index.php (unless it's redirecting you to index.html, if that's the case then there's the problem).